# Drop down list to multiple of text maximizing 255 characters

Tags: sharepoint-server, list, infopath

I have drop down field on infopath form which comes from external list (from other SP list by data connection). This drop down list only accepts 255 Characters. When user select from drop down field it brings huge numbers of character from external list, and there are not able to submit the form.
So that, How can I change this drop down list to multiple of text, maximizing 255 characters.

NB:

I just tried to check the Allow unlimited length checkbox on the list column's properties page, But I can't have option in SharePoint list.

Comment: How can I change this drop-down list to multiple of text **Where** in InfoPath or sharepoint list?

Comment: Where ever Mohe, I need best options to soleve it. Thanks as always

Comment: I am sorry @Sara, but I still can't get your point, do you have a drop-down control on InfoPath form and you need to convert it to multiline textbox?!

Comment: Is that possible to change to multiple on InfoPath?

Answer (score 1):

There is a limit on choice column:

> Choice Maximum value: 255 Size per column: 30 bytes
>
> Choice (multiple selection): Maximum value: 350, Size per column 22 bytes

More details see [software boundaries and limit for SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/mt493258(v=office.16).aspx)